# How to preserve in pyspark a value across consecutive rows based on condition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I'm on Spark 3.0.1 and this is an exemplification of my pyspark DataFrame:

```
| label| amount| bool   |
 ----------------------------- 
| a    | 10    | false  |
| a    | 2     | false  |
| b    | 20    | true   |
| c    | 3     | true   |
| d    | 2     | false  |
| f    | 5     | false  |
| w    | 50    | true   |
...
...
```

This is the code I used to produce aforementioned exemplification:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({
     'label': ["a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "w"],
     'amount': [10, 2, 20, 3, 2, 5, 50],
     'bool': [False, False, True, True, False, False, True]
     }))
```

I'd like to perform a task which seems to me really simple but that I'm not managing to achieve.

In particular I'd like to:

1. order by `label` (already assumpted in the example)
2. assign to a new  `true_label` column, values as such:

   - the value in `label`, if `bool` is `false`
   - the latest (following the `label` ordering) `label` already met with a `false` in `bool`

An update of the previous example should help for a better understanding of the expected result:

```
| label| amount| bool   | real_label |
 ----------------------------------- 
| a    | 10    | false  | a          |  <- because `bool` is false, `real_label` = `label`
| a    | 2     | false  | a          |  <- because `bool` is false, `real_label` = `label`
| b    | 20    | true   | a          |  <- because `a` the latest `label` with a `false` in `bool` 
| c    | 3     | true   | a          |  <- because `a` the latest `label` with a `false` in `bool` 
| d    | 2     | false  | d          |  <- because `bool` is false, `real_label` = `label`
| f    | 5     | false  | f          |  <- because `bool` is false, `real_label` = `label`
| w    | 50    | true   | f          |  <- because `f` the latest `label` with a `false` in `bool` 
...
...
```

Is It possible to achieve what I want without knowing the number of consecutive `false` I can meet and also given that the real dataframe is very big and performance matter (so toPandas-based answers are unfortunately proibitive and would also be better to avoid `udf` functions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window function `last` to get the previous "false label" if true, otherwise keep the label.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'real_label',
    F.when(
        F.col('bool'),    # get previous false label if true
        F.last(
            F.when(~F.col('bool'), F.col('label')),    # keep false labels and mask true labels with null
            ignorenulls=True
        ).over(Window.orderBy('label'))
    ).otherwise(F.col('label'))    # otherwise keep label if false
)

df2.show()
+-----+------+-----+----------+
|label|amount| bool|real_label|
+-----+------+-----+----------+
|    a|    10|false|         a|
|    a|     2|false|         a|
|    b|    20| true|         a|
|    c|     3| true|         a|
|    d|     2|false|         d|
|    f|     5|false|         f|
|    w|    50| true|         f|
+-----+------+-----+----------+
```

Comment: Stunningly clear, sir. This indeed was what I wanted to achieve. Simple and performant. The last function had not jumped to my eye nor would I have thought of using it in such an elegant way. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## A solution using SQL

```
yourDF.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp_view")
    
yourTransformedDF = spark.sql("""SELECT 
        label, 
        amount, 
        bool, 
        label2,
        CASE WHEN bool THEN LAG(COALESCE(label2, label)) OVER (ORDER BY label) 
             ELSE label
        END AS real_label
    FROM (
      SELECT
        label,
        amount,
        bool,
        case when bool then LAG(label) OVER (ORDER BY label) else label end as label2
      FROM tmp_view) q""")
```